# Cells in parallel combination

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, batteries

> [image: Blockquote]

This is an excerpt from my book and I am not able to understand how could “V” be equal to Ε<sub>1</sub>- I<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub> as well as Ε<sub>2</sub>- I<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub>.

 I mean One battery could have emf of 50 volt and another just 5 volt. So, How could 50 be equal to 5? How could voltage across both the batteries be same?

 
 And I also wonder if both the batteries were of equal emfs, would there be any current? Because that would be like two persons pushing with equal force but in opposite direction.

 I mean electrons coming from two equal cells E<sub>1</sub> and E<sub>2</sub> in parallel combination (as in above figure), won’t they push against each other with equal force and hence no current should flow?

Comment: This configuration deals with non ideal conductors, modeled as Ohm resistors, as you can realise looking at the voltage difference between $B_1$ and $B_2$ containing the voltage drop $-r_k I_k$

Comment: What a poor way to write a textbook. Where did this monstrous notation come from?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a numerical example will help with the assumption that there is no external circuit connected to the batteries?

[image]

Applying Kirchhoff's voltage law to loop $ABCDA$,

$-5-v_1-v_8+50 = 0 \Rightarrow -5-i\cdot 1-i\cdot 8+50 = 0$

Hence $ i= 5\,\rm A$, $v_1 = 5\,\rm V$ and $v_2 = 40\,\rm V$.

So in that loop there is a voltage drop of $5+40 = 45 \,\rm V$ which is the difference between the emfs of the two batteries.

*How could voltage across both the batteries be same?*

The potential of node $A$ relative to node $C$ is $5\color{red}+ 5\cdot 1 = 10\,\rm V = 50 \color{red} - 5\cdot 8$

Note also that the  $50\,\rm V$ battery is being discharged and $5\,\rm V$ battery is being "charged" and can think of the $50\,\rm V$ battery being discharged as wasted energy and over time will mean that it has supplied no useful energy to an external circuit.

*I also wonder if both the batteries were of equal emfs, would there be any current?*

Without an external circuit present there would be no current on the loop $ABCDA$.

In practice (nearly) identical batteries are put in parallel so that each battery delivers a portion of the current demand of an external load.